# perl: why are references to anonymous arrays scalar?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, scalar

I haven't programmed in Perl in over 10 years so maybe this is something obvious to more experienced Perl programmers. I searched for an answer but didn't find anything.

My question is: why are references to anonymous arrays scalar?

For example in the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my @array1 = ('one');
say 'array ref 1: ' . \@array1;
my @array2 = ('one', 'two');
say 'array ref 2: ' . \@array2;
say 'array ref 3: ' . \('one');
say 'array ref 4: ' . \('one', 'two');

exit 0;
```

The result is:

```
array ref 1: ARRAY(0x1e1b1c0)
array ref 2: ARRAY(0x1e1b190)
array ref 3: SCALAR(0x1e1b280)
array ref 4: SCALAR(0x1e10c40)
```

Why are array ref 3 and array ref 4 scalar?

Comment: Try also `say 'array ref 5: ' . ['one', 'two'];`

Comment: There are no anonymous arrays in your examples :-)

Comment: This is explained in [Arrays vs. Lists in Perl: What's the Difference?](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl) under "Arrays can be referenced." (I recommend reading the rest of the article, too, since many Perl programmers don't realize that there's a difference between lists and arrays.)

Comment: Thanks ThisSuitIsBlackNot I read that article about Arrays vs Lists and it cleared things up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All references are scalars. When you stringify a reference, it includes the type of what it's referencing. That means you have a reference to a scalar.

`[ ]` is the operator that constructs an array. `( )` doesn't create any arrays.

You want

```
say 'array ref 3: ' . ['one'];
say 'array ref 4: ' . ['one', 'two'];
```

---

Normally, parens just change precedence. If that were true here,

```
\('one', 'two')
```

would be equivalent to

```
('one', \'two')
```

That's because a comma/list operator in scalar context normally returns that to which its last expression evaluates. But `\(...)` is special-cased to be equivalent to the following more useful construct:

```
(\'one', \'two')
```

> Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of references!
>
> ```
> @list = (\$a, \@b, \%c);
> @list = \($a, @b, %c);      # same thing!
> ```

That means that

```
say 'array ref 4: ' . \('one', 'two');
```

is equivalent to

```
say 'array ref 4: ' . (\'one', \'two');
```

which is equivalent to

```
say 'array ref 4: ' . \'two';
```

Answer (score 8):

From [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

> Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of references!
>
> ```
> @list = (\$a, \@b, \%c);
> @list = \($a, @b, %c);      # same thing!
> ```

You get a scalar reference because the item in the list that ends up with its reference passed to the LHS is a scalar.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you expect that these are equivalent:

```perl
my @array1 = ('one', 'two');
my $array2 = \('one', 'two');
```

But that is not the correct syntax to get an anonymous array. You need square brackets to create an anonymous array.

```perl
my $array3 = ['one', 'two'];  # a reference to an anonymous array
my $array4 = \['one', 'two']; # a reference to a reference to an anonymous array
```

Comment: It's not likely you'll ever need `\['one', 'two']`.

Comment: @ikegami I agree with you on that, but the question was not about practical or real use cases, it was about how the language works, so I added that simply for illustrative purposes.